# javascript rendered HTML page still loading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mother page, where is jvscrpt function called openWin() , which opens a new window.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin()
{
win=window.open();
win.document.write("<html>");
win.document.write("<head>");
win.document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">");
win.document.write("@media print{.input {display:none}}");
win.document.write("</style>");
win.document.write("</head>");
win.document.write("<body>");
win.document.write("<table align=\"center\">");
win.document.write("<tr><td>result:</td><td>100,--€</td></tr>");
win.document.write("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" id=\"idcko\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"click\" class=\"input\" onclick=\"window.print();\"/></td></tr>");
win.document.write("</table>");
win.document.write("</body>");
win.document.write("</html>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="openWin();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on button "Click me!" a new window appears, but browser can`t stop loading the page.The page has full functionality,but for example when I want to see source code in Mozilla, I get only a blank page.
Please help...

Comment: Its not related to the opening a new window, its just realted to using document.write when a document has already finsihed writing. If you do document.write('test') (after load) on the current page you get the same effect. The reason they are the saem is because window.open() will be opening a new page with a complete but empty document. I'd suggest trying to use DOM functions to add your HTML elements which should be a bit better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call

```
win.document.close();
```

At the end(after the last write() )

It signals to the browser that the write-process is finished and the document is complete.

Comment: Damn. I thought I tried that in my tests with no joy. I probably got the case wrong or something. ;-) Good job though. :)

Answer (score 1):

> but for example when I want to see
>   source code in Mozilla, I get only a
>   blank page.

This is because the source was written by your javascript - this is the same as AJAX (you can't view the changes in the source).

Perhaps you would be better of just opening a new page and pass whatever paramters it needs either via a GET/POST or server-side.